# Extra Gap coming between table top and table header top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UITableView having issues.

For first time arrival on the screen this gap appears.once we come back from next screen, it will come ok.
I tried out all the ways for removing this space and i am not able to do that except i use this.

```
self.membershipTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0);
```

this shows the time interval ok first time but when we come back from next screen it shows the gap at bottom.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvGxp.png)

When i checked out the subviews, i found that there are 5 subviews in the table which includes header and footer. i am attaching the log. please do check it and let me know why this issue comes. For other tables, everything is fine.

*sudhir_table ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 128}>
2015-11-17 11:50:50.019
[3054:65135] sudhir_table >
2015-11-17 11:50:50.019[3054:65135] sudhir_table >
2015-11-17 11:50:50.020[3054:65135] sudhir_table >
2015-11-17 11:50:50.020[3054:65135] sudhir_table >*

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not use proper method for creating height of header and footer,
use this code for header height...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return 0.002f;// set this...
 }
```

and also can use this one.

```
self.membershipTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

you should use -64.0f instead of (-64, 0, 0, 0), must add .0f at the end of each value.

Comment: How it make difference for 64.0f and 64 except theoretical differences because it is giving me same result and i have used the method u specified to fix the height of header view.but still issue is appearing.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.membershipTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64.0f, 0, 0, 0);
    self.membershipTable.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    self.membershipTable.frame=CGRectMake(5,0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-10, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-114);  
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.005f;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.005f;
}